# What's the name of this two icons?

Tags: flutter, icons

do you know what's this icons name? The icons before update and delete.

[image]

Comment: I think update and delete Icon are custom, there not in Icons package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are custom icons if you want something similar you could check
[For material icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.set=Material%20Icons)

or
[For cupertino icons](https://itsallwidgets.com/cupertino-icons-gallery-the-home-of-over-1335-cupertino-icons-used-in-flutter)

but for custom icons, you could check [Flaticons](https://www.flaticon.com/search?type=icon&word=trash) or any website similar which they have more Icons than(material or Cupertino)